# What was samkhya's criticism on vedanta?

Tags: philosophy, vedanta, advaita, sankhya

From a [site](https://gosai.com/writings/mayavada-and-buddhism-are-they-one-and-the-same) I read the following passage of strong criticism on Sankara's Vedanta.

> Later philosophers also declared Mayavada to be crypto-Buddhism. The Sankhya philosopher Vijnana-bhiksu (1550–1600 CE) tried to reconcile Vedanta with Sankhya philosophy and synthesize all theistic
>   schools of Indian thought into a philosophy that he called Avibhagadvaita(indistinguishable non-dualism). He was an impartial writer who analyzed both the merits and problems of the various doctrines that he encountered. Concerning Sankara’s philosophy, Vijnana-bhiksu states in his Sankhya Pravacana Bhasya:
>
> > brahma-mimamsayam kenapi sutrenavidya-matrato bandhasyanuktatat.
> >      avibhago vacanaditya-sutrair-brahma-mimamsaya
> >     abhipretas-yavibhaga-laksanadraitasy-avidyadivastavatve’pyavirodhaccha.
> >     yat tu vedanta-bruvanamadhunikasya mayavadas-yatra lingam drsyate tat
> >     tesamapi vijnanavadyeka-desitaya yuktameva.
>
> There is not a single Brahma-sutra in which bondage is declared to be a mere deception. As to the novel theory of maya propounded by vedanta-bruva (those who claim to be Vedantists), it is only another type of Buddhist of the Vijnanavada school (vijnana-vadyekadesin). This theory has nothing to do with Vedanta and it should be understood that this doctrine of these new Buddhists, who assert the theory of maya and reduce our bondage to mere illusion is in this way refuted. (Sankhya Pravacana Bhasya 1.22)
>
> Later on in his work, Vijnana-bhiksu also quotes the famous verse from Padma Purana (mayavadam asat-chastram). Vijnana-bhiksu considered Buddhism to be nastikavada, or atheism, as it was opposed to Vedic thought. Thus, in effect, he was declaring Mayavadis to be out and out atheists.

I want to know if he was the only one or there were any other samkhya scholars who criticized Vedanta?

Comment: Vijnabhikshu criticized advaita vedanta and not whole vedanta. Advaita is not the only Vedanta. You should make clear that you are looking for criticism on Advaita if you are looking for similar criticism.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma yes i know that is why I gave one example and asked if any one else has criticized any vedanta? Is it so difficult to comprehend ??

Comment: There is a misconception in people that Advaita is the default or the only principle in Vedanta.  When you completely speak of advaita in the question and ask about criticism on Vedanta, they may understand advaita = Vedanta. That would be misleading. That's why I asked.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma i have clearly mentioned sankara vedanta criticism with example and asked if any such things are said by other scholars. If someone assumes vedanta as sankara then its their wish...

Comment: Vijnanabhikshu was a weird figure who was simultaneously a member of the Samkhya school and the Vedanta school.  He believed in a Vedantic philosophy called Avibhagadvaita.  And just like anyone who believes in a particular Vedantic philosophy, he thought the other Vedantic philosophies are wrong.  It's just like Ramanujacharya criticizing Advaita.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan but even rAmAnuja subscribed to pancharatra and vedanta.. But Vijnana was kind of more neutral reference as he was into samkhya and yoga chiefly and in Vedanta to an extent and went though available works of vedanta...

Comment: Now as I said Vijnanabhikshu was a weird figures who believed in multiple Astika schools at once, but usually a person only belongs to one of the six Astika schools.  So other than Vijnanabhikshu, all other members of the Samkhya school rejected the Vedanta school as a whole, and not just particular Vedantic philosophies like Vijnanabhikshu did.  Samkhya works like Kapila's Samkhya Sutras, Ishwara Krishna's Samkhya Karika, and the Yukti Dipika disagree with the Vedanta school.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Vijnanabhikshu actually thought that Vedanta was the ultimate truth from the Paramarthika perspective, and that Samkhya and Yoga are only true from the Vyavaharika perspective.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan any reference ?

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Vijnanabhikshu discusses this in the beginning of his Samkhya Karika Bhashya.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan can you give that verse. I think no harm in believing two schools together

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78990/discussion-between-keshav-srinivasan-and-rakesh-joshi).

Comment: Samkaya doesn't believe in God. Hence it is opposed to all schools of Vedanta - including the dualistic. A 'modified' Samkaya appears in the the Bhagavata Purana. Read Dasgupta's "History of Indian Philosophy" Volume 4.

Comment: The Samkhya doctrine never criticized any other doctrines. That's the way it shd be. It's the Vedanta philosophy that is criticizing a whole lot of other systems. But who cares? If they are scriptures then all Darshanas have the same authority as others. So, how can one Darshana refuting another be authoritative? @RakeshJoshi

Comment: I think the weirdest was Vācaspati who commented everywhere. @KeshavSrinivasan This guy commented on Yoga sūtra, Nyāya sūtra, Sāṅkhya kārikā and even followed advaita and specially, he was the disciple of Maṇḍana Miśrra, and had training in Mīmāṁsā specially.